# What is a good clustering/classification algorithm on WEKA for ECG frequencies/amplitudes?

Tags: algorithm, classification, cluster-analysis, weka

I'm using WEKA to classify Healthy Babies vs. Babies that have shown risk factors for SIDS. I'm currently trying to using the maximum frequencies and that point's amplitude to see if you can determine risk factors from that data. I only have data from about 20-25 babies.

Is there a particular classification or clustering algorithm on WEKA that would be good for this type of analysis?

Comment: You *really* need to try different things to see what works on *your* data. All these methods wouldn't exist if there was a clear pattern of which is best when.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression is probably worth trying. I would try hard to find out from experts which features might be signs of SIDS and then to find data which gave me information on those features.

Comment: I've been trying to locate sources on it, but everything that sounds like it's what I need requires me to pay for access. Ill give Logistic regression a shot though thanks.